# Hierarchical error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
    with t(branch_id, branch_code, branch, parent_branch_id, level) as
  (
    Select parent_b.BRANCH_ID, parent_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           parent_b.BRANCH, parent_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID, 0 as level
    from table parent_b
    Where parent_b.branch_Id is null--= 1
    UNION ALL
    Select child_b.BRANCH_ID, child_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           child_b.BRANCH, child_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID, (t.level+1)
    from table child_b 
    INNER JOIN t parent
       ON parent.branch_id = child_b.parent_branch_id
  )
  select * from t
```

And i get error in ouput. Where is the error, i can't find.

Error:

> The multi-part identifier "t.level" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `t.level` to `parent.level`. You have given an alias to CTE as `parent'. you need to use that.

```
  with t(branch_id, branch_code, branch, parent_branch_id, level) as
  (
    Select parent_b.BRANCH_ID, parent_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           parent_b.BRANCH, parent_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID, 0 as level
    from table parent_b
    Where parent_b.branch_Id is null--= 1
    UNION ALL
    Select child_b.BRANCH_ID, child_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           child_b.BRANCH, child_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID, (parent.level+1)
    from table child_b 
    INNER JOIN t parent
       ON parent.branch_id = child_b.parent_branch_id
  )
  select * from t
```